# Mysql INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE responce

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a table A and I want when a new value (not UPDATE) is inserted in that table to do an INSERT in table B, I tried to play with the responce of the $query INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but no luck, it always returns 1.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table ".$fields." VALUES ".$values." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated=1"
$response = $dbc->query($query);
if($response == 1)
```

I have also tried a 'hack' lets say, putting the UPDATE above the INSERT so if the entry doesnt exist to fail but that again returns 1 everytime.

```
 $query = "UPDATE table SET updated=1 ..;
 $response = $dbc->query($query);
 if($response == 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @boomoto for helping me figuring out the answer:

```
 $query = "UPDATE tableA ..
 $response = $dbc->query($query);
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)==0){
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO tableB ..
        $response2 = $dbc->query($query2);

        $query = "INSERT INTO tableA ..
        $response = $dbc->query($query);
    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tableA ".$fields." VALUES ".$values." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated=1");

if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)==1)
{
   mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tableB ".$fields." VALUES ".$values.");
}
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to do it without an additional Query for performance issues, tableA is going to be very big and there are going to be many INSERTS calling this query. So if a SELECT takes 5s and I have 2000 INSERTS each day with this solution it will take 20000s